# How to use Parameterized query using TypeORM for postgres database and nodejs as the application's back-end server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I want to fetch the rows from a postgres table where name = SUPREME INT'L,
Note: this string has a single quote in between the name characters.
I am using TypeORM as an ORM, POSTGRESQL as the database.

My query:

```
 import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';
 const connection =  getConnection();

 var query = `SELECT * from skusimulations where "name"= ? `;
 const output =await connection.query(query, ['SUPREME INT'L'])
```

I am getting error while executing this, I want to escape the single quote by using stored proc.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error? Are you referring to your failure to escape the single quote in your literal, because the query itself looks like it is already using parameter escaping.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, yes indeed I used stored proc to escape the single quote. Btw I solved it by storing the "name" in a variable and passing the variable in the replacement array, another modification was instead of '?' changed it to $1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOLVED:
Thanks for giving your time to my question, I really appreciate it.
I changed a few things by referring to the typeorm.io docs. 
 FINAL CHANGES:-

```
  var name = "SUPREME INT'L" ;
  var query = `SELECT * from skusimulations where "skuId"= $1 `;
  var skuData =await connection.query(query, [name])
```

Comment: this was really helpful, thanks! , if someone need this for mssql (like me) you just need to change the $ for  @ and the position parameter start with 0

Answer (score 1):

for mysql `await getEntityManager().query('SELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE name = ?', [ p_name ])`

for mssql `await getEntityManager().query('SELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE name = @0', [ p_name ])`

for postgres   `.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ANY($1)', [[1,2,4]]`

below worked for me in case of mssql driver

[image]

for more info https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/556