# Adding OR condition with other than entity column in typeorm gives error: could not determine data type of parameter $2

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I want to generate postgres query as below:

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
where param.name is null or t1.name ilike param.name
```

Here param is request parameter

I tried with this:

```
await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder("t1")
        .innerJoinAndSelect("t1.table2","t2")
        .where("t1.name ilike :name or :name is null",{ name:`%${request.body.name}%`)
        .getMany()
```

This returns following error:

QueryFailedError: could not determine data type of parameter $2

Comment: Possibly Postgres cannot determine the type of :name.  As it is comparing to text in the ilike part it is automatically converted, but you might need to do .... cast(:name as text) is null.... as null has no type to convert to.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Parameterized query using TypeORM for postgres database and nodejs as the application's back-end server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684928/how-to-use-parameterized-query-using-typeorm-for-postgres-database-and-nodejs-as)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the example and got the same error, from my experience I think this is a bug with typeorm

I suggest you change your aproach to the problem, try this:

```
await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder("t1")
        .innerJoinAndSelect("t1.table2","t2")
        .where("t1.name ilike :name",{ name: req.body.name ? `%${request.body.name}%` : '%%')
        .getMany()
```

this will work the same as the provided query.

Answer (score 0):

I used below query to meet my need:

```
    await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder("t1")
               .andWhere(new Brackets(q => {
                    q.where("d.name ilike :name", { name:`%${request.body.name}%`})                      
                    q.orWhere("cast(:param as character varying) is null", { param: request.body.name || null})
                }))
```